# Does WSO2 API Manager 1.10 supports MariaDB

Tags: wso2, mariadb, wso2-api-manager, api-manager

I have question about mariaDB with WSO2 API Manager 1.10.0. I found document about Tested DBMS supporting WSO2 API Manager. https://docs.wso2.com/display/compatibility/Tested+DBMSs
 This page mentions that MariaDB was not tested for WSO2 API Manager 1.10, otherwise it was tested for WSO2 API Manager 1.9.0.
 I'd like to get some test result for mariaDB with WSO2 API Manager 1.10.0. Do you have any plan to test for mariaDB with WSO2 API Manager 1.10.0?
 If not, would you let me know how to test mariaDB with it? I'd like to get some information about test.

Answer (score 2):

You can connect mariaDB to APIM 1.10.0 with mysql connector. You can follow this document for how to use mariaDB with Carbon products. I couldn't guarantee they test the mariaDB with APIM 1.10 .

https://docs.wso2.com/display/Carbon420/Setting+up+MariaDB

Comment: Thanks, Shanika.
I wonder how to test for mariaDB with 1.10.0. I'd like to test for mariaDB in the same way.